# android - base activity click listener

Tags: android, clicklistener

I have an BaseActivity which all of my other activities extending this. I have a public item which my all activites can open it. How can i listen this view's click from my BaseActivity ?

Example

```
 Activity 1 (Base) > VideoActivity > LoginView
 Activity 1 (Base) > MusicActivity > LoginView
```

I have a button in login view and when i click it gives an  error that VideoActivity don't have a method clicklistener. My click listener method is at baseActivity

Waiting for your help
Thanks

Comment: "when i click it gives", you means, when you try to setOnClickListener with LoginView.this?

Comment: Do you have the code? That would probably help with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `LoginView extends BaseActivity` and `BaseActivity implements OnClickListener`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new YourOnClickListener(), LoginView.this);
```

If this doesn't fix your problem then please post relevant code